# Does Huawei's super charging affect the battery?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, huawei, performance

I have a Huawei P20 pro and it came with a "super charger" that can take full charge the phone's battery really quickly. Sometimes in less than an hour.

I wonder if this affects the battery's lifespan! Will the battery degrade overtime due to how fast the super charger works?

I'm interested specifically in Huawei's super chargers.

Comment: I don't think so. fast charging feature is related to its processor.

Comment: please go through this link which describe technically, https://www.quora.com/What-is-fast-charging-How-does-it-work

Comment: I don't think that you will get a definitive answer to that topic. However in general the battery temperature increases more with fast charging. And high temperatures can fasten battery degrade.

Answer (score 1):

Battery charging is an ongoing field. There isn't conclusive evidence that fast charging itself is bad. However, fast charging have a measurable impact on battery life in the field

https://www6.slac.stanford.edu/news/2014-09-14-study-sheds-new-light-why-batteries-go-bad.aspx
http://ecec.mne.psu.edu/Pubs/2018_Yang_JPS.pdf

Other variables include discharge rate or temperature also have an effect on battery life too. Like any engineering problem, fast charging is a trade off. The loss of battery life may not be pronounced as the normal 2-year life span usage rate.

Please note, fast charging is not part of the USB standard. Qualcomm, Huawei, Oppo and Apple create their own implementations.

Even worse, lots of cables break the USB C power spec.

https://www.theverge.com/tldr/2016/11/8/13564460/usb-c-spec-apple-cables-port-future-macbook

https://bensonapprovedcom.wordpress.com/

Benson Leung regularly validates cables ever since a third party cable kill a chrome pixel.

I am not sure what will happen if you mix up different chargers.